# Java - Regular Expression to check if the string contains continuous digit along with other characters

Tags: java

I am looking to write regular expressions to check if a string contains below:

1. It contains continuous digit which ranges from 2 to 5 digits.
2. It contains continuous digit of more than 9 digits.

For example:

1. Hello, my address is 1 MG Road  - Returns false
2. Hello, I stay at 100 Feet Road -  Returns true
3. Can you call me 9999273732. this is my number - retuns true.
4. My pin code is 313002 - retuns false.

Comment: Here it is `(\\d{2,5}|\\d{9,})`.

Comment: Downvoted because no attempt whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^\D*(?:\d{2,5}|\d{9,})\D*$
```

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MSOKbU/2/)

Short explanation (You can also visit the demo to see an explanation):

- `^`: Start anchor
- `\D*`: Any amount of non digits
- `(?:`: Start of a non capture group
- `\d{2,5}`: 2-5 digit s
- `|`: Alternator
- `\d{9,}`: 9 or more digits
- `)`: End of non capture group
- `\D*`: Any amount of non digits
- `$`: End anchor

If you use any of the methods:

- `String.matches()`
- `Pattern.matches()`
- `Matcher.matches()`

Then you don't have to specify the start and end anchor, `^` and `$`

Comment: just wondering: why do we need a non-capturing group here?

Comment: @AminM OP doesn't want to capture anything, they only want to check if a `String` matches the regex, so we don't need a capture group, but it would also work if we used one.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)(\\d{2,5})(?!\\d)|\\d{9,}"); 
    Matcher matcher =
            pattern.matcher("111lo, I stay at 100 Feet R10034");  // your input here

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.format("I found the text" +
                        " \"%s\" starting at " +
                        "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                matcher.group(),
                matcher.start(),
                matcher.end());
    }
```

Short explanation:

- `(?<!\\d)` : negative lookbehind that matches with character that isn't a digit
- `\\d{2,5}` : digits of length 2 to 5
- `(?!\\d)`  : negative lookahead that  matches with character that isn't a digit
- `|` : alternation
- `\\d{9,}` : matches digits of length 9 or more

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that.

```
fun checkDigit(inputValue: String): Boolean {
    var isContinueDigit = false
    var digitSize = 0

    inputValue.forEach {
        if (it.isDigit()) {
            if (isContinueDigit) {
                digitSize++
            } else {
                isContinueDigit = true
                digitSize = 0
                digitSize++
            }
        } else {
            isContinueDigit = false
        }
    }

    val isDigit: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(2, 3, 4, 5, 9)
    return isDigit.contains(digitSize) || isDigit.last() < digitSize
}
```

Comment: OP didn't mention that they use kotlin

Comment: Yea. I forgot about that . Thanks  I will be careful next time

Comment: this is not my question, number like 2,5 means (eg. 4456,25,45625,254,)and above 9 means( eg 985674236)

Comment: whatever you share thanks for that but please help for this

Comment: 2,5 means the size of elements. And above 9 means size also. So it does not mean only numbers with from 2 until 9. It is only for the size of the array